# Compare 24 hours format times in moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

How to compare two times which are in 24 hours format. I have tried below lines of code?

```
     $("#dd_start_timing, #dd_end_timing").on('keyup change keydown', function() {
        var DutyDayStartTime = $("#dd_start_timing").val().trim();// 13:05
        var DutyDayEndTime = $("#dd_end_timing").val().trim(); // 13:05
        if(DutyDayStartTime.minute() === DutyDayEndTime.minute())
        {
          alert("cannot be same");
        }
});
```

I am using moment.js library. It throws error message "DutyDayStartTime.minute is not a function". Please help me how will I compare two times in moment.js

Comment: the better will be if u help me in finding the difference

Comment: if the diffrence is 0 which means the time is same

Comment: DutyDayStartTime is a variable that you declare. It will not return you result like calling this DutyDayStartTime.minute(). Because it don't have minute function.

Comment: `var now = moment(new Date()); //todays date
var end = moment("2015-12-1"); // another date
var duration = moment.duration(now.diff(end));
var days = duration.asDays(); // (asHours() as required )`

Comment: i am not passing any dates. I am passing time directly in those two variables.. so i need to compare times only

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: *"i am not passing any dates. I am passing time directly in those two variables"* no, you are passing two **strings** that some people might read as time definitions. Strings don't have a `minute` method. But if your format is always `HH:mm` you don't need to convert them into `moment`-objects to check wether these two strings are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to use moment js library.

```
var moment = require("moment")

var DutyDayStartTime = moment([13,05], "HH:mm")
var DutyDayEndTime = moment([13,05], "HH:mm")

DutyDayStartTime.diff(DutyDayEndTime, 'minutes') // 0
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to just compare two time variable, then you can simply use;

- `isSame()`
- `isSameOrBefore()`
- `isSameOrAfter()`
- `isAfter()`
- `isBefore()`

moment.js functions. Those functions returns `boolean` result as `True` or `False`. More from the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/).

```
var DutyDayStartTime = moment($("#dd_start_timing").val().trim(), 'HH:mm');// 13:05
var DutyDayEndTime = moment($("#dd_end_timing").val().trim(), 'HH:mm'); // 13:05
if(DutyDayStartTime.isSame(DutyDayEndTime))
{
  alert("cannot be same");
}
else if(DutyDayStartTime.isBefore(DutyDayEndTime))
{
  alert("duty day start time cannot be before");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

date1 = moment('01:01', 'HH:mm')

date2 = moment('02:01', 'HH:mm')

dif = date2.diff(date1, 'minutes')

Answer (score 1):

Compared their timestamps

```
var DutyDayEndTime = moment('13:05', 'HH:mm');
var DutyDayEndTime = moment('13:05', 'HH:mm');
if(DutyDayStartTime.unix() === DutyDayEndTime.unix()){
 console.log('cannot be same')
}
```

[JSFiddle Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/gihanmu/3xay2ewn/10/)